# Вложенные циклы в ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, yml

Прошу помощи в работе с вложенными циклами в Ansible.
Почему-то в документации вложенными циклами называются комбинированные циклы, собственно и примеры не несут полезной нагрузки.
Столкнулся с такой задачей: есть некоторая сущность (назовем ее `out_1`), которая содержит в себе несколько идентичных `results`. По типу такого:

```
results:[{result[0]}, {result[1]}, ...,{result[n]}]
```

Чтобы получить каждый отдельный элемент необходимо применить какие-либо варианты ansible loop, например

```
with_items: {{ out_1.results }}
```

Тогда, каждый элемент становится доступен через `{{ item }}`
    Но, в моём случае, в каждом блоке `result[i]` лежит так же список `stdout_lines`
    и мне необходимо перебирать эти значения. Не знаю как к нему обратиться.
    Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказки.

Comment: Вам для каких целей? Вдруг вам хватит обычного шаблонного `{% for %}` тега

Comment: Я несколько раз вызываю shell команду с разными параметрами, в выводе может не быть ничего, а могут вывестись значения в несколько строк: каждое значение в отдельной строке. Значения складываются в переменную, которая указана в register. Т.к. shell-запросов несколько, то и результатов вывода тоже несколько, они и являются этими result[i]. Далее мне необходимо пройтись по всем result и по всем строкам, которые были выведены, чтобы на их основе опять же сформировать новую shell-команду.

Comment: все значения из переменной register можно собрать через json_query в один массив и уже им оперировать
debug: msg="{{ mydict | jsonquery(myquery) }}"
vars:
 myquery: "[*].needed_key"

Answer (score 1):

все значения из переменной register можно собрать через json_query в один массив и уже им оперировать

```
debug: msg="{{ mydict | jsonquery(myquery) }}"
vars:
 myquery: "[*].needed_key"
```